# Changing the text in an HTML <p> tag depending on which canvas image a user clicks

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mousedown

I have an HTML5 canvas which is displaying a number of images. I have used the KineticJS library to draw the images and make them draggable, however, I'm using a local copy of the library, since there are one or two changes I wanted to make to its functionality.

I now want to add some more functionality to the `mousedown` function in the library, but I'm not exactly sure of how to do what I want to, and I'm just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction?

I currently have about 30 images being displayed on the canvas- the images are all stored in a hidden section in the HTML, and have been added to a JS array from there. I also have another JS array, in a separate JS file, which contains an array of textual descriptions about each of the images in the image array.

The text at position 0 in the text array is the description for the image at position 0 in the image array, text at position 1 for image at position 1, etc...

I have and HTML `<p></p>` tag on my page below the canvas.

What I now want to do is add a function that will change the text displayed in that `<p></p>` tag depending on the image that has been clicked on on the canvas... i.e. add some code to the `mousedown` function, that says

"when a `mousedown` is detected on an image, find out what position in the images array that image is stored at, and update the text in the `<p></p>` tag to display the text stored at the corresponding location in the text array.

Theoretically, I would have thought that this should be fairly straightforward, but I'm just not sure how to do it... Presumably I need to write a new JS function, i.e.

```
function displayTip(){
    document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML= tips[0];
}
```

and then call that function from within the `mousedown` function in the library.

What I'm not sure about is how to find out what position the image that's been clicked on is in the images array, so that I can store it in a variable, and then set the `tips[]` value to the value of that variable, to give me the same position in the tips array.

I assume I'm going to need to edit the `mousedown` function in the library a little bit, to tell it to find out what array position the image that's been clicked on is at, but I'm not sure how to do this... any ideas?

The `mousedown` function currently looks like this:

```
_mousedown: function(evt) {
    this._setUserPosition(evt);
    var obj = this.getIntersection(this.getUserPosition());
    if(obj && obj.shape) {
        var shape = obj.shape;
        this.clickStart = true;
        shape._handleEvent('mousedown', evt);

    }

    //init stage drag and drop
    if(Kinetic.DD && this.attrs.draggable) {
        this._initDrag();
    }
}
```

Also, I assume that once I have found out where in the array the image is stored, I will then want to add a call to my `displayTip` function in the `mousedown` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding in the following function:

```
function displayTip(index){

    document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[index];
    console.log("displayTip being called");
}
```

to my JavaScript, and calling it from within the `mousedown` function using the line:

```
displayTip(obj.shape.index);
```